# Can't seem to get the debugger for c/c++ working in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

Every time I start up the debugger it give this message in the console: "The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)" and a few seconds later "[New Thread 5864.0x1564]". I just pulled down the latest eclipse for c/c++ for this because I couldn't figure out how to get c99 to run on visual studio 2012. I just need to implement a simple merge sort and I think I have an off by one error somewhere but can't get the debugger working.

I'm using windows 7 64-bit, eclipse IDE for c/c++ developers, cygwin and c99.

Comment: What's the problem here?  x86 is little endian.  Is this just a general usage question?

Comment: The problem is that that console output is all I get when I try to run the debugger. It doesn't Change perspective or run until a break point like it does with Java.